# ObjectReferenceValue not updating in CustomPropertyDrawer

Tags: oop, pass-by-reference, unity-editor, scriptable-object

i am trying to create a custom property drawer that lets me open and edit properties of a scriptable object however i want it to be done so that if i create a new scriptable object this way (only in memory and not on disk) then it should create a new instance of it.

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(CharacterData))]
public class CharacterDataPropertyDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);
        if (GUI.Button(position, "Edit Properties"))
        {
            if (property.objectReferenceValue == null)
            {
                property.objectReferenceValue = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<CharacterData>();
                if (property.objectReferenceValue == null)
                    Debug.Log("this is still null");
            }
            EditorUtility.OpenPropertyEditor(property.objectReferenceValue);
            //EditorUtility.OpenPropertyEditor(ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<CharacterData>());//This works but does not get saved obviously
        }
        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }
}
```

I was expeting taht i would be able to create a new instace of this criptable object and edit it but i always get the debe that this is still null.

i tried using apply serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties(); but that did not work out either